How do you self-label posts in the BlueSky/ATProtocol API?
For a variety of reasons, I'm communicating with the BlueSky API directly using requests rather than using one of the client libraries.
I have everything operating correctly (including facets, what fun), but some of the posts should be self-labeled... but cannot figure out from the documentation how to self-label a post (or blob).  Does anyone have any pointers?

Add this key-value pair to the record:
"labels": {
    "$type": "com.atproto.label.defs#selfLabels",
    "values": [
        { "val": "label-name" }
    ]
}

values is an array which can contain multiple {"val": "label-name"} values. The labels you can use are porn, sexual, nudity or graphic-media.
labels is added on the record level, so on the same object that holds the text and the embed:
{
    $type: "app.bsky.feed.post",
    createdAt: "2024-12-19T08:43:21.433Z",
    langs: ["en"],
    text: "Test",
    "labels": {
        "$type": "com.atproto.label.defs#selfLabels",
        "values": [
            { "val": "nudity" }
        ]
    }
}

And yeah, the documentation is very lacking... I figured this out myself by setting these labels manually on Bluesky and examining the network traffic it generated. It also worked well when I tested it myself.
